# How to get rid of the annoying block cursor highlighter (adjusting the cursor thickness)

Tags: windows-8, cursor

I have this annoying problem where my cursor on a select few documents comes up as the cursor shown in this picture:

[image: Picture]

How do I change this? I have a brooding suspicion that this is a Windows feature problem.

I would like to add that this happened after a friend of mine messed about with the Windows features, such as **magnify**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I get rid of the annoying block cursor highlighter?

> I would like to add that this happened after a friend of mine messed about with the Windows features, such as magnify."

The above is the clue to solving your problem.

Please check your "Ease of Access" settings:

- Goto: `Control Panel` > `Ease of Access Center` > `Make the computer easier to see` > `Set the thickness of the blinking cursor`.
- Make sure it is set to `1`.

  > [image]

Notes:

- The instructions might be slightly different for Windows 8.
- When it set to `20` I see the same block cursor that you do.

Answer (score 2):

It is *either* a windows 8 feature problem, or you have pressed the <kbd>Ins</kbd> key.

Press the <kbd>Ins</kbd> key again to get that cursor out of your way!

Comment: That was my first go to and it is certainly not why I am getting a block cursor. It is definitely a windows 8 feature problem.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala Go on with the error reporting!
Also, Try restarting windows, or try repairing notepad using add or remove programs!

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor thickness has been increased. My two- year-old did this to my Windows 8.1 PC with a little button mashing. Follow these easy steps to return to normal:

- In Windows 8.1, go place the cursor in the top right corner of the screen to access at the charms menu and select **Settings**.
- In the bottom right corner of the settings menu select **Change PC Settings**.
- In the PC Settings Menu select **Ease of Access**
- In the Ease of Access Menu select **Other Options**
- At the bottom of the page in the Visual Options section see the **Cursor Thickness Slider** and **slide it all the way to the left**.

Your cursor will now appear as a flashing `|` instead of a block.

Comment: This is a good answer, however, it is also exactly the same as the answer that was accepted as correct. Please read the entire thread to see if you're adding anything new, and if you do have something new and worthwhile to add, then do so.

Comment: Entirely the same answer, so I cannot award any points to this